# clang-format -style=file not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, clang, ubuntu-18.04, clang-format

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with clang-format 9.

I've read the [clang-format](https://releases.llvm.org/9.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) documentation where it says:

> clang-format supports two ways to provide custom style options: directly specify style configuration in the -style= command line option or use -style=file and put style configuration in the .clang-format or _clang-format file in the project directory.
>
> When using -style=file, clang-format for each input file will try to find the .clang-format file located in the closest parent directory of the input file. When the standard input is used, the search is started from the current directory.

No matter how I create the `.clang_format` file (I've tried with `clang-format -style=google -dump-config > .clang_format`) or where I put it, if I execute `clang-format -style=file <file>` it doesn't format anything.

Anyone that have the same issue?

For example, if I have a file `hello.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio>

std::string s=" VERY BAD"
"FORMATTING";

int   main()   {
  std::cout<< "Hello world!"<<'\n';
  return 0;


}
```

If I run:

```
$ clang-format -style=mozilla -dump-config > .clang_format
```

and even if I don't edit the `.clang_format` file, then

```
$ clang-format -style=file hello.cpp
```

I get the default LLVM formatting style instead of the Mozilla style:

```
#include <stdio>

std::string s = " VERY BAD"
                "FORMATTING";

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello world!" << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

but if I run `$ clang-format -style=mozilla hello.cpp` then I get

```
#include <stdio>

std::string s = " VERY BAD"
                "FORMATTING";

int
main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello world!" << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

and the same happens if I move the previously generated `.clang_format` in the parent directory of the `hello.cpp` directory.

I've tried anything but it seems that I have to stick with preconfigured styles.

Anyone with the same problem?

Can I get some sort of logging from clang-format?

**SOLUTION**:

the name of the file must be `.clang-format`, not `.clang_format`!

Comment: I doubt anyone has memorized the subtle differences between Mozilla and LLVM style. What's supposed to be different, and did you actually verify the setting in your .clang-format?

Comment: I've edit the question with the code formatted accordingly to the Mozilla style. I used `clang-format -dump-config` so I assume that the `.clang_format` file should be correct. I swear I've tried any possible combination of `.clang_format` file / settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was creating a configuration file with a wrong name.

It must be named `.clang-format`, not `.clang_format`.

Answer (score 1):

`clang-format -i <file>` is sufficient if you've placed your .clang-format file at the project root. The `-i` stands for in place. The commands you paste should have spit a formatted file out to standard output. The reason for this is that clang-format won't alter your file by default. Seems weird for a formatter at first, but it's a good safety precaution, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that clang-format doesn't automatically reformat my file. The text that I get in stdout it is not reformatted following my custom `.clang_format` file.

Comment: Examples in the question would be beneficial. clang-format works just fine for me; it's likely you're using an option that only kicks in when it has to and not all the time.

Comment: Like my answer, if you omit `-style=file`, does it work? I don't explicitly say to use a file after I've configured one, and it works fine for me.

Comment: It doen't work even if I omit `-style=file`. I'm thinking about report a bug

Comment: This is my last-ditch effort, but since it sounds like you installed the package `clang-format-9`, do you have to invoke it in the same way? The only thing I can think of now is that you're not actually using version 9. I haven't had this issue on Debian using linuxbrew, or on my Mac.

Comment: Ok I have finally found the error! I was naming the configuration file `.clang_format`, but it should be named `.clang-format`. It was a stupid mistake! Thank you for your support sweenish.